# Can't make select work properly with ngmodel

Tags: angular, select, ngmodel, angularjs-ng-value

I have a "lookup" select which needs to work as a "passive" control: highlight the selected option and as an "active" control: let user select the option and initiate some action (load corresponding entity's details). I tried a lot and can't make it work properly:

```
            <select
              class="browser-default custom-select"
              (ngModelChange)="onEdit($event)" [(ngModel)]="selected.id" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
              <option [ngValue]="null">{{ '::Licences:SelectLicence' | abpLocalization }}</option>
              <ng-container *ngIf="licencesLookupData$ | async">
                <option
                  *ngFor="let l of licencesLookupData$ | async"
                  [ngValue]="l.id"
                  [selected]="l.id === selected.id"
                >
                  {{ l.id }} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{ l.displayName | defaultValue }}
                </option>
              </ng-container>
            </select>
```

At first, I have tried to avoid ngModel, but then I had the problem with id - it is an integer, but was treated as a string. Now the types are correct (numbers), but the selected option is never selected, even though the correct data is loaded and selected.id gets a number value.

Lookup is an ordinary observable with numeric id key:

```
  licencesLookupData$: Observable<Common.Lookup<number>[]>;

  export interface Lookup<T> {
      id: T;
      displayName: string;
  }
```

onEdit method:

```
  onEdit(id?: number) {
    if (id === null) {
      this.onAdd();
      return;
    }
    this.licencesLoading = true;
    this.licencesService
      .getById(id)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.licencesLoading = false)), takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe((state: Licences.LicenceWithFlatProperties) => {
        this.selected = state;
        this.buildForm();
        this.get();
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials, this is what finally worked for me:

```
  <select
    class="browser-default custom-select"
    (change)="onEdit($event.target.value)"
  >
    <option [value]="">{{
      '::Licences:SelectLicence' | abpLocalization
    }}</option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="licencesLookupData$ | async">
      <option
        *ngFor="let l of licencesLookupData$ | async"
        [ngValue]="l.id"
        [value]="l.id"
        [selected]="l.id == selected.id"
      >
        {{ l.id }} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{ l.displayName | defaultValue }}
      </option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>

  onEdit(idString: string) {
    const id = Number(idString);
    if (isNaN(id)) {
      this.onAdd();
      return;
    }
    this.licencesLoading = true;
    this.licencesService
      .getById(id)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.licencesLoading = false)), takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe((state: Licences.LicenceWithFlatProperties) => {
        this.selected = state;
        this.buildForm();
        this.get();
      });
  }
```